# How to calculate PCKE's code_verifier?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, okta

I'm going through [Okta's PCKE Flow demo](https://www.oauth.com/playground/authorization-code-with-pkce.html) to get a better understanding of how it works, and I'm having trouble reproducing the same `code_challenge` hash that's being generated from the `code_verifier`. Here's a screenshot of the demo:

[image: Pcke Flow Demo]

Using `Zg6klgrnixQJ629GsawRMV8MjWvwRAr-vyvP1MHnB6X8WKZN` as the code verifier, how did they produce
`iF_7prUeJ6rr3jMG3LmhW3R1cZ2ecZavFqS0jtb6tzo` as the code challenge?

Using this [SHA256 hash calculator](https://xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) and [Base64 Encoder](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url/encode), I got `ODg1ZmZiYTZiNTFlMjdhYWViZGUzMzA2ZGNiOWExNWI3NDc1NzE5ZDllNzE5NmFmMTZhNGI0OGVkNmZhYjczYQ` which doesn't match the expected value of `iF_7prUeJ6rr3jMG3LmhW3R1cZ2ecZavFqS0jtb6tzo`. What am I doing wrong to not get the expected value?

This [SHA256 base 64 hash calculator from approsto](https://approsto.com/sha-generator/) gives me a value that is very close to the expected value. Using this calculator I get `iF/7prUeJ6rr3jMG3LmhW3R1cZ2ecZavFqS0jtb6tzo` which is one character off from the expected value (notice how there's a `/` instead of `_`).

What am I doing that's causing this discrepancy? How do I calculate the expected `code_verifier` value of `iF_7prUeJ6rr3jMG3LmhW3R1cZ2ecZavFqS0jtb6tzo`? Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The PKCE code challenge is the Base64-URL-encoded SHA256 hash of the verifier. This means you need to take the original string, calculate the SHA256 hash of it, then Base64-URL-encode the hash. That's a lot of words, so let's walk through it.

There are two problems with what you've tried to do above:

The online SHA256 hash calculator you found outputs the hash as a hex-encoded string rather than the raw bytes. That's typically helpful, but in this case is not. So the next thing you're doing by base64 encoding is that you're base64 encoding the hex representation of the hash rather than the raw bytes. You need to use a hash function that outputs the raw bytes, and pass the raw bytes into the base64-url-encoder.

The next problem is that you need to base64-url encode, not base64 encode. Base64-URL-encoding is a minor variation of Base64 encoding, where the only difference is using the character `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/`, and trimming the `=` padding characters from the end. This makes it URL-safe, since otherwise the `+/=` characters would need to be escaped in the URL.

So, to calculate the PKCE code challenge, you need to use a SHA256 function that can give you the raw bytes, then use a modified Base64 encoding function to encode those bytes.

Here is some code in PHP that will do that:

```php
function pkce_code_challenge($verifier) {
    $hash = hash('sha256', $verifier, true);
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($hash), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

It's also possible in plain JavaScript in a browser, but the code is slightly longer due to the complexity of the WebCrypto APIs:

```js
function sha256(plain) { 
    // returns promise ArrayBuffer
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = encoder.encode(plain);
    return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
}

function base64urlencode(a) {
    // Convert the ArrayBuffer to string using Uint8 array.
    // btoa takes chars from 0-255 and base64 encodes.
    // Then convert the base64 encoded to base64url encoded.
    // (replace + with -, replace / with _, trim trailing =)
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(a)))
        .replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
}

async function pkce_challenge_from_verifier(v) {
    hashed = await sha256(v);
    base64encoded = base64urlencode(hashed);
    return base64encoded;
}
```

Comment: Hey! I've been watching you on Youtube. Thank you for the very detailed answer. Also thanks for the content you've been putting out as it has been very helpful (esp. the video of the advantages of PCKE over implicit flow). In case anyone else is reading, I was able to get the expected value by declaring your JS functions and calling `await pkce_challenge_from_verifier("Zg6klgrnixQJ629GsawRMV8MjWvwRAr-vyvP1MHnB6X8WKZN")`

Comment: So we don't need to pad the code challenge with the `=` character?

Comment: @PeterSchorn - Looks like the `=` padding isn't required. According to the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648): *"The pad character "=" is typically percent-encoded when used in an URI [9], but if the data length is known implicitly, this can be avoided by skipping the padding; see section 3.2."*

Comment: Hey, Are there any online urls that do this "input (code verifier)->sha256 (binary value)->to base64urlencode" conversion so i can follow along without writing any code?
I'm going from https://string-o-matic.com/sha256 to sha256 the input (tried all the options i thought there)
then Base64 that result here:
https://www.base64encode.org
But not getting the code_challenge result.

Comment: Check out https://example-app.com/pkce it's a tool I made to help debug these kinds of things

Answer (score 4):

Based on Aaron's example and hacking the pkce-challenge node package, here's what I use:

```
class PkceChallenge {
    random(length, mask) {
        let result = "";
        let randomIndices = new Int8Array(length);
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(randomIndices);
        const byteLength = 256
        const maskLength = Math.min(mask.length, byteLength);
        const scalingFactor = byteLength / maskLength;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += mask[Math.floor(Math.abs(randomIndices[i]) / scalingFactor)];
        }
        return result;
    }

    base64UrlEncode(array) {
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(array)))
            .replace(/\+/g, '-')
            .replace(/\//g, '_')
            .replace(/=+$/, '');
    }

    generateVerifier(length) {
        const mask = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~";
        return this.random(length, mask);
    }

    generateChallenge(length = 43) {
        this.verifier = this.generateVerifier(length);

        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const data = encoder.encode(this.verifier);
        return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data).then(array => { return { code_challenge: this.base64UrlEncode(array), code_verifier: this.verifier }; });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "qwe" | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '='
```

where is qwe is code_verifier

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and wanted to create the `code_challenge` within Postman as a pre-request script and came up with the following. Might help you if you try to achieve the same. My `code_verifier` is set in an environment and the challenge value will be saved to the environment as well:

```
pm.environment.set(
    "code_challenge",
    CryptoJS.SHA256(pm.environment.get("code_verifier"))
        .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
        .replace("+", "-")
        .replace("/", "_")
        .replace(/=+$/, "")
)
```

Comment: This answer helped me, but I ran into an issue when the encoded value contained more than one plus sign and had to modify it.
`var code_challenge = CryptoJS.SHA256(code_verifier).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64).replaceAll("+", "-").replaceAll("/", "_").replace(/=+$/, "");`