# Spotify PKCE code_verifier was incorrect

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, pkce

I was excited to hear that I can now use the Spotify web API without having a backend application via PKCE. Unfortunately, I seem to have some sort of misunderstanding and have been unable to get it to work.

I am likely making some minor mistake along the way, but I did it once to no avail and I wiped the slate clean and tried again but still without luck. From this I gather that I must be misunderstanding the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce).

I will explain what I am doing and hopefully someone here can point out what I'm missing or doing wrong. I'm assuming I have a fundamental conceptual misunderstanding.

I first generate a cryptographically random string using an npm package called crypto-random-string. I store that in the browser's local storage before using js-sha256 to hash it and then using another npm package called base64url to encode it.

```
    let verifier = cryptoRandomString({length: 50})
    window.localStorage.setItem('verifier', verifier)

    let params = {
      client_id: '[MY CLIENT ID]',
      response_type: 'code',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
      code_challenge_method: 'S256',
      code_challenge: base64url(sha256(verifier))
    }

    let endpoint = new URL('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize');
    endpoint.search = new URLSearchParams(params);

    window.location = endpoint.toString();
```

From here, I redirect to the /authorize endpoint with the proper url parameters. I have gotten this far successfully and then been redirected accordingly to my provided redirect_uri, where I grab the given code from the url parameters.

At this point, I try the fetch to the /api/token endpoint with the client_id, grant_type, the code I got from the url params, my redirect_uri, and the locally stored code_verifier.

```
    let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log(params.get('code'));

    let newParams = {
      client_id: '[MY CLIENT ID]',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: params.get('code'),
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
      code_verifier: window.localStorage.getItem('verifier')
    }

    let endpoint = new URL('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token');

    endpoint.search = new URLSearchParams(newParams);

    fetch(endpoint.toString(), {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).then(data => data.json()).then(console.log)
```

At this point, after both of my attempts I received the error:

```
{ error: "invalid_grant", error_description: "code_verifier was incorrect" }
```

Is there anything that I am obviously doing wrong? The error leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong as far as the actual generation of the code_verifier, but I am at a loss to what that issue may be.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Running into the exact same problem here. I'm pretty sure it's not the encoding but I can't tell what Spotify is doing on their end.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I took some time off from this project because I felt like I exhausted my options. I'm going to try to look at it again with a set of fresh eyes in the near future and I'll be sure to update this thread if I make any progress.

Comment: Okay. I'll let you know if I find anything. No clue what is going wrong though, I guess the documentation is too new and maybe slightly inaccurate somewhere.

Comment: I also asked on the Spotify developer forums [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Unable-to-use-PKCE-authorization-code-verifier-was-incorrect/m-p/5006416#M811)

Comment: Great. Thank you. Part of the reason I believe it is a problem on my end is because [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Spotify-PKCE-Auth-Invalid-Client-Secret/td-p/4989309) in the first reply, a person claimed to have done a "proof of concept" with this flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone on the Spotify forum pointed me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911194/how-to-calculate-pckes-code-verifier/59913241#59913241) answer. Not sure why exactly, but doing the encoding the following way does work:

```js
    async function sha256(plain) {
      const encoder = new TextEncoder()
      const data = encoder.encode(plain)
    
      return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data)
    }
    
    function base64urlencode(a){
      return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(a))
        .replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '')
    }
    
    const hashed = await sha256(verifyCode)
    const codeChallenge = base64urlencode(hashed)
```

Comment: Can someone confirm if this is still working? I can't seem to get this to work, and Spotify's api error message isnt detailed enough to debug the issue :|

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers and comments, in addition to OP, has documented most information needed so I will only add what helped me:

The verifier **itself** most be encoded as a Base64-URL.

Pseduo-code (as I myself code in C#):

```
verifier = Base64UrlEncode(GetRandomString(length: 50))
challenge = Base64UrlEncode(HashWithSha256(verifier))
```